# How to create seperate files using one template that contains different content with grunt bake?

Tags: html, node.js, web, gruntjs

I have one template that is styled in a certain way. I have multiple content that I want to display each within that template. Is it possible to do that with bake?

https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake

E.g.:
My template looks like this:

```
<div style="background-color:red">

</div>
```

Content 1:

```
<p>Content 1</p>
```

Content 2:

```
<p>Content 2</p>
```

Content 3:

```
<p>Content 3</p>
```

It should be displayed like this:
File 1:

```
<div style="background-color:red">
  <p>Content 1</p>
</div>
```

File 2:

```
<div style="background-color:red">
  <p>Content 2</p>
</div>
```

File 3:

```
<div style="background-color:red">
  <p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

At the end I get 3 sperate files. The template is always the same. The only differy in the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having briefly read the documentation for [grunt-bake](https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake), I'm quite certain that it *does not* meet your requirement. Like many of the other grunt template plugins, `grunt-bake` will require a separate `.html` template for each file/content you need to insert. I.e. Each separate template will need to include it's custom placeholder/marker such as:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <!--(bake path/to/your/content1.html)-->
  </body>
</html>
```

...as shown in the [example](https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake#simple-bake) on the projects repo. Given your scenario you would need to have three `.html` templates that each define a different path to the file that holds the content to insert. Which is not what you want!

However, it is fairly trivial to achieve your requirements without a grunt plugin and create your own custom [Task](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#creating-tasks) instead.

The following gist shows how this can be achieved:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Note: Configure the following paths according to your directory structure...
  var config = {
    // Obtain the content from the template .html file.
    template: grunt.file.read('./src/templates/template.html'),

    // Define the path/glob to the partials/content .html files.
    partials: './src/partials/*.html',

    // Define the path to the output directory where the resultant files
    // should be saved to. Path must include a trailing forwards slash.
    dest: './build/'
  }

  grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
  });

 /**
  * Registers a custom Task to insert content into the template.
  * Loops over each partial .html file and reads its content.
  * The placeholder <!--{{insert}}--> found in the template is replaced
  * with the newly read content/partial and a new file is written to disk.
  */
  grunt.registerTask('buildContent', 'Append partials to template', function() {
    grunt.file.expand(config.partials).forEach(function (file, index) {
      var outputFilePath = config.dest + 'File-' + (index + 1)+ '.html',
        contentToInsert = grunt.file.read(file),
        content = config.template.replace(/<!--{{insert}}-->/g, contentToInsert);

      grunt.file.write(outputFilePath, content);

      // Log message to console.
      grunt.log.writeln('File created: ' + outputFilePath);
    });
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'buildContent' ]);
  // ...
};
```

---

**Template**

In the `Gruntfile.js` you will notice the line reading:

```js
content = config.template.replace(/<!--{{insert}}-->/g, contentToInsert);
```

This simply replaces the comment placeholder `<!--{{insert}}-->` with the content for *Content 1 (2,3 etc)*. So it will be necessary to add that comment to your template. For example:

```html
<div style="background-color:red">
<!--{{insert}}-->
</div>
```

This can of course be another comment placeholder. You just need to make sure that whatever you choose, exists in both the `replace` function of the custom Task and is placed in your actual `.html` template.

**Directory structure:**

The `Gruntfile.js` gist assumes a directory structured as follows. This can of course be different, you'll just need to configure the paths for `config.template`, `config.partials`, and `config.dest` accordingly.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── template.html
│   └── partials
│       └── content1.html
│       └── content2.html
│       └── content3.html
├── Gruntfile.js
├── package.json
└── ...
```

*Note: Each file in the `partials` directory holds only the content to be inserted into the template. For example the content of `content1.html` is only:*

```html
<p>Content 1</p>
```

**Running the custom Task**

Running `$ grunt` via your commandline using the `Gruntfile.js` gist above will generate a `build` folder with the newly created `.html` files:

```
.
└── build
    ├── file-1.html
    ├── file-2.html
    └── file-3.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Just hopping in to mention that it seems the grunt-bake library now supports it as mentioned in the documentation

https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake#bake-extra-pages-eg-detail-pages

Maybe some people searching for this in 2019 or later can benefit from this :)